# Hiding file extension on in combobox directory listing

Tags: c#, combobox

Can't work out how to hide the file extension on a directory listing when in a ComboBox.

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Modules");
foreach (string file in files)
ModuleComboBox.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`

Comment: as @ArturoMenchaca said. `files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Modules").Select(x => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x))`

Comment: And then `ModuleComboBox.Items.AddRange(files.ToArray());` and the work is completed.... who writes the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

I'm sorry for the first answer

```
ModuleComboBox.Items.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));
```

Comment: That is not the way to use this method

Comment: It's name is `GetFileNameWithoutExtension` not `GetFileName**S**WithoutExtension`